# Spring HATEOAS: How to advertise resource services?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas

I've got Spring HATEOAS working for accessing a specific resource, such as

```
http://localhost:8080/user/1
```

But I want to also be able to advertise a service url:

```
http://localhost:8080/user
```

For instance, if you do a GET / , I want to return the service resources I advertise.  Right now the only one is /auth.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public HttpEntity<AuthenticationResource> post() {
    AuthenticationResource resource = new AuthenticationResource();
    resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(AuthenticationController.class).authenticate()).withSelfRel());
    return new ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResource>(resource, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/auth", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public void authenticate() {
    //users.save(user);
}
```

Currently this is not compiling because linkTo doesn't take a void argument, which I presume is the return type of my authenticate method

What I WANT is this:

```
{"links":[{"rel":"someString","href":"http://localhost/auth"}]}
```

How do I accomplish this while staying within HATEOAS best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public HttpEntity<ResourceSupport> post() {
    ResourceSupport resource = new ResourceSupport();
    resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(AuthenticationController.class).authenticate()).withRel("authenticate"));
    return new ResponseEntity<ResourceSupport>(resource, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/auth", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public HttpEntity<AuthenticationResource> authenticate() {
    AuthenticationResourceAssembler assembler = new AuthenticationResourceAssembler();
    AuthenticationResource resource = assembler.toResource(new Authentication());

    return new ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResource>(resource, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: This is not related to the issue of your question, but you should inject an Autowired AuthenticationResourceAssembler instead of creating on at each POST...